# Possible to import particle system animation from Blender into Unity, and turn it into working particles in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, particles, particle-system

I just went through a Blender tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgmJsLcLXUI) that showed how to create a morphing particle system animation in Blender. He ended up creating 2 layers, with a separate example on each.

The particle system animation, when played on the Timeline, looks very cool in Blender. Now I'm wondering how, or if I even can, to properly bring it into Unity and basically turn it into particles within Unity.  I was hoping i'd be able to create a Shuriken Particle System in Unity, using the exported Blender file as the mesh shape.

But anyway, I've tried like 4 different ways of exporting from Blender and importing to Unity, and I can't get Unity to recognize it the way I need it to. Any tips on how to make this process work, or if it's even possible to ultimately do what I'm trying to do re: the title?

Comment: Particles are a simulated animation, blender calculates the positions for each frame. To transfer a simulation from blender to unity you would need to keyframe the location of each particle and import those animations into unity. I would suggest using unity's particle system to replicate the same animation. While alembic support works with animated meshes, I'm not sure it will work with particles.

Comment: @sambler Thank you for helping me. When you say, `you would need to keyframe the location of each particle and import those animations into unity` , although I understand you do not recommend it VS Unity's built-in particle system, do you mean exporting each individual particle's animation from Blender as separate files? Because I actually did see someone posted a tool to do something like that. The tool didn't work for me when I tried it, but I might pursue it again if it seems like the 'correct' way to deal with Blender/Unity particle export cases. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvQxiuchiDQ

Comment: By making each particle a real object and animating it to match the particle movement, you should be able to export the animation of each object to unity. This appears to be what that script is meant to do. Many export formats that support animation also support multiple objects in the one file.